# Merge values of multiple arrays in object with jQuery or underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I want to merge values of multiple arrays in one object to one array.
For instance:

```
Object:
  - alpha: Array[3]
     0: "vatG4d6mcjKbpfuAm"
     1: "xkQrKEsfwuYPkDcdz"
     2: "GDg9chZnDGrbLXWGS"
  - bravo: Array[1]
     0: "53LEcQ5MoYXFyvktf"
  - …
```

The result should be:

```
["vatG4d6mcjKbpfuAm", "xkQrKEsfwuYPkDcdz", "GDg9chZnDGrbLXWGS", "53LEcQ5MoYXFyvktf"]
```

I did this with a simple for loop iterating over the elements, but I am concerned about the performance. Is this possible with a simple jQuery or underscore.js function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A simple loop is probably more performant than any library call. *Measure* performance instead of being concerned.

Comment: In fact, jQuery's `merge` does exactly that. It just loops through the supplied arrays: `merge:function(first,second){ for(;j<len;j++){ first[i++]=second[j]; }` (And some more stuff)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to use a library for this.

For two arrays use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var arr = obj.alpha.concat(obj.bravo);
```

For more than two arrays use a loop:

Either with `concat` again

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in obj) {
  arr = arr.concat(obj[k]);
}
```

Or using the `push.apply` method

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in obj) {
  arr.push.apply(arr, obj[k]);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ow7r6308/2/)

Make a function using this information so you don't need to repeat code:

```
function mergeObjectArrays(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    arr.push.apply(arr, obj[k]);
  }
  return arr;
}

var arr = mergeObjectArrays(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

with jquery you can use [merge](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

```
var newArray = $.merge(array1, array2);
```

with underscore you can use [union](http://underscorejs.org/#union)

```
var newArray = _.union(array1, array2);
```

Comment: `_.union` does a merge; but it will only return unique values.

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the arrays using pure javascript like this:

```
var obj =
{
    alpha: ["vatG4d6mcjKbpfuAm", "xkQrKEsfwuYPkDcdz", "GDg9chZnDGrbLXWGS"],
    bravo: ["53LEcQ5MoYXFyvktf"]
};
var obj.charlie = obj.alpha.concat(obj.bravo);

// obj.charlie = ["vatG4d6mcjKbpfuAm", "xkQrKEsfwuYPkDcdz", "GDg9chZnDGrbLXWGS", "53LEcQ5MoYXFyvktf"]
```